# Trouble understanding this sudoku solver recursion function (python)

Tags: python, recursion

So basically I decided to make a sudoku solver in python and recursive functions is most efficient, but I've been trying to understand this code from a youtuber and don't understand why each space (bo[row][col]) doesn't immediately reset to 0.  The resetting of one space to 0 only occurs if solve(bo) is True, but if I look through the code, the board will only return True if the board is completely solved, so why doesn't this function just lead nowhere since solve(bo) will never be True?

```py
def solve(bo):
    find = find_empty(bo)

    if not find:
        return True  # This is the only time that solve(bo) == True
    else:
        row, col = find

    for i in range(1, 10):
        if valid(bo, i, (row, col)):
            bo[row][col] = i

            if solve(bo):
                return True

            bo[row][col] = 0   # Yet here it resets the space to 0 if solve(bo) is False

    return False


def valid(bo, num, pos):
    for i in range(9):
        if bo[pos[0]][i] == num and pos[1] != i:
            return False

    for i in range(9):
        if bo[i][pos[1]] == num and pos[0] != i:
            return False

    box_x = (pos[1] // 3) * 3
    box_y = (pos[0] // 3) * 3

    for i in range(box_y, box_y + 3):
        for j in range(box_x, box_x + 3):
            if bo[i][j] == num and (i, j) != pos:
                return False

    return True


def find_empty(bo):
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if bo[y][x] == 0:
                return (y, x)
    return False
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reset every single time"? Every function call frame? If so, it's because the parameter is just a reference to an object in memory. There's only one board the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some discrepancy  between your explanation and comments in the code, but I'll do my best to explain the code anyway.

First solve() will try to find the first empty spot (i.e. one that is 0). If it can't find any, then the board is solved so it returns true.

If it *does* find a spot, then it will try to place numbers 1-9 there and check if it works with the previously entered numbers. Say 7 works (we don't know if 8 or 9 work as well because we haven't checked that yet). So we set the empty space to 7 and then pass this updated board in a recursive call. Essentially, this is like saying "if I force this spot to have the number 7, can you find a solution?"

If the recursive call returns true, it means there is a solution with 7 in that spot and hence the board has a solution, so we return true. If the recursive call to solve() returns false, then we know that there is no solution to the board with 7 in this spot, so we reset this spot to 0 and then try 8 (and then 9 if needed).

The thing to remember is that there is only one board (`bo`) in all the recursive calls - in other words, all the function calls are operating on the same variable `bo`. It doesn't create a copy of the board every time you make a recursive call. Lookup 'Pass by reference' and shallow vs. deep copies if you want to learn more about why.